# What are these trees with tall trunks and narrow wispy leaves?

Tags: identification, trees

Does anyone know what [these trees](http://i1.wp.com/sugarandcharm.com/scwp/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MollywoodDesign-7.jpg?w=600) are?

We've got a tight retaining wall where we want to plant some trees.

[image]

Comment: standard oleander? Hard to tell with a photo that far away

Answer (score 3):

The standards look like Olive trees, or Olea europae, interspersed with clipped Box balls (Buxus sempervirens) with a few Cyclamen persicum (the low one with white flowers) dotted about. The cyclamen shown may be purely temporary visitors because they're the houseplant variety in temperate regions.